# Force Entity Framework to return a new instance

Tags: entity-framework, orm, identity-map

We have a scenario in our code when only a few properties of an entity are allowed to be changed. To guarantee that, we have code similar to this:

```
public void SaveCustomer(Customer customer)
{
    var originalCustomer = dbContext.GetCustomerById(customer.Id);

    if (customer.Name != originalCustomer.Name)
    {
        throw new Exception("Customer name may not be changed.");
    }

    originalCustomer.Address = customer.Address;
    originalCustomer.City = customer.City;

    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

The problem with this code is that the call to `dbContext.GetCustomerById` does not always gives me a new instance of the `Customer` class. If the customer already has been fetched from the database, Entity Framework will keep the instance in memory and return it on every subsequent call.

This leads us to the actual problem - `customer` and `originalCustomer` may refer to the same instance. In that case, `customer.Name` will be equal to `originalCustomer.Name` and we will not be able to detect if it differs from the database.

I guess the same problem exists with most other ORMs as well, because of the identitymap design pattern.

Any ideas how this can be solved? Can I somehow force EF to always give me a new instance of the customer class?

Or should we refactor the code instead? Does anyone know of any good design patterns for this scenario?

Comment: Where does `GetCustomerById` come from? Also, what is the lifetime of your context?

Comment: Ah, sorry. GetCustomerById is only a wrapper method for DbSet<TEntity>.Find(). The lifetime is per HTTP request.

Comment: If you don't want `Name` to be changed simply don't allow upper layer code to work with `Customer` entity (= create new class where `Name` will be readonly) or hide the setter.

Answer (score 1):

you can try by detaching the entity from the context, this will remove all the references to the context (as well as the identitymap behaviour).
So, before passing the Customer to your method you can detach it:

```
yourContext.Detach(customer);
```

Comment: This is technically correct answer. If you want to get fresh instance from database you must first detach previous instance from the context.